# Parsing error from string to JSONArray in Android Application

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

I want to receive from an MySQL-Server all my data from a table.
So, I wrote a PHP script that fetches the complete table and encode it to JSON format.

PHP-Code:

```
<?php
include ("connect.php"); 

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM MyTable);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
$buffer[] = $row;
}

print json_encode( $buffer );
mysql_close($dbconnect);
?>
```

So, when I run the script, all the JSON String looks fine, no corupted characters etc.

In Android App:

When I run the following codes and receive the JSON String throught the HTTP, I get a strange String in the Debugger...

Screenshot: http://goo.gl/gTssQ

### Java Code:

```
String result = "";
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        // HTTP Verbindung
        try
        {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://mywebsite.com");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Fehler bei der http Verbindung "+e.toString());
        }



        try
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"utf-8"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }



        try
        {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
            {
                json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);


                    );
            }
        }
        catch(JSONException e)
        {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }
```

---

I cant understand the Problem, because my Database is full UTF-8 and my script too.
I hope someone can help me! :-)
Greets, andr3w

Comment: What is strange with that, looks like JSON to me?! What is the error you get. Pleas post your error message.

Comment: You're missing a `'` in this line: `$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM MyTable);`. Strange if it is a typo (you didn't cut/paste the code?) but even stranger if it isn't :)

Comment: Hi! Sorry, yes I forget during copy/paste the '